# Clear Numbers from text and paste as values from external workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Im looking for solution of my project. 
I have source data `workbook_src` and destination `worbook_dest`. In `workbook_src` are numbers in format `="123456789"`. My goal is open `workbook_src` as read only, copy row with numbers to memory, clear them to numbers only and paste special to `workbook_dest` as value.

Open `workbook_src` as readonly

```
Dim src As Workbook
Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:\xxx.xlsx", True, True)
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

Function for clear numbers

```
Function GetNumeric(CellRef As String)
    Dim StringLength As Integer
    StringLength = Len(CellRef)
    For i = 1 To StringLength
        If IsNumeric(Mid(CellRef, i, 1)) Then Result = Result & Mid(CellRef, i, 1)
    Next i 
    GetNumeric = Result
End Function
```

But i have problem get this function to applicated on whole row

Comment: You cannot apply this function on the whole row. You need to loop through the row and apply it on each cell.

Comment: ok but can be done via VBA ? becosue use it fo each cell nice when i have 10 000+ cells
     
    =GetNumeric(F2)

Comment: I didn't undetstand anything of your comment above. Sorry.

Comment: Sure this can be done with VBA, use a simple loop. A loop in VBA doesn't care if it runs 1, 10 or 10 000+ times.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution

```
Function cleanString(str As String) As String
    Dim ch, bytes() As Byte: bytes = str
    For Each ch In bytes
        If Chr(ch) Like "[A-Z.a-z 0-9]" Then cleanString = cleanString & Chr(ch)
    Next ch
End Function

Sub btn_CleanAll()
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A30000").Cells
    rng.Value = cleanString(rng.Value)
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```